# libgdx - iOS landscape not working right with scene2d

Tags: ios, iphone, libgdx, landscape, scene2d

I'm having an issue with libGDX's otherwise great scene2d ui library when running my app in landscape mode. My program works as expected in both the android simulator and the desktop environment, but when I run it on the iOS simulator or a real device, the main menu is drawn as if the phone were still in the portrait orientation, and the just cropped to fit in a landscape view. At first, I assumed I had just screwed up, as I'm still learning the api, but the app works just as expected on android. I have configured my game to run in landscape mode on both iOS and android.

On the android simulator, the menu works as expected. The simulator is in landscape orientation, and properly displays the menu.

On iOS, the menu is off center and unclickable.

I pretty sure that the problem has to do with landscape mode, because everything works fine in portrait orientation. Here's my code for the MainMenuScreen, which extends a ScreenAdapter.

```
package bakpakin.techgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ScreenAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton.TextButtonStyle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ChangeListener;

/**
 * Created by Calvin on 9/25/14.
 */
public class MainMenuScreen extends ScreenAdapter {

private TechGame game;
private Stage stage;
private Skin skin;
private Table table;

public MainMenuScreen(TechGame game) {
    this.game = game;
}

@Override
public void show() {
    this.stage = new Stage();
    this.skin = new Skin();

    skin.add("default", Assets.superScript48);
    skin.add("title", Assets.superScript128);

    TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = skin.getFont("default");
    textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetY = 4;
    skin.add("default", textButtonStyle);

    Label.LabelStyle labelStyle = new Label.LabelStyle();
    labelStyle.font = skin.getFont("title");
    labelStyle.fontColor = Color.CYAN;
    skin.add("default", labelStyle);

    // Create a table that fills the screen. Everything else will go inside this table.
    table = new Table();
    table.setFillParent(true);
    stage.addActor(table);

    final TextButton play = new TextButton("Play", skin);
    final TextButton about = new TextButton("About", skin);
    final TextButton quit = new TextButton("Quit", skin);

    play.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            Assets.button1Sound.play(1, 1, 0);
        }
    });

    about.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            Assets.button1Sound.play(1, 1, 0);
        }
    });

    quit.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            Assets.button1Sound.play(1, 1, 0);
            Gdx.app.exit();
        }
    });

    final Label title = new Label("My Game", skin);

    VerticalGroup vg = new VerticalGroup();

    vg.pad(60);

    table.add(title);
    table.row();
    table.add(vg);

    vg.addActor(play);
    vg.addActor(about);
    vg.addActor(quit);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    GL20 gl = Gdx.gl;
    gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    stage.dispose();
    skin.dispose();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IOS 7 or 8? I heard there are some iOS 8 rendering issues

Apparently this is fixed in the latest snapshot (see github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2386). With a new stable release promised real-soon-now, I'm sure the fix will be folded in if you're not brave enough to run snapshot builds

Comment: Im using iOS 8.0 (550.1)